# Is there a way to stop root logins from the initial login screen without locking root account?

Tags: ubuntu, root

I'm experimenting with different settings for my machine with Ubuntu 12.04.  I'm trying a login screen that requires typing in the username first, and then the password, instead of listing the users, as an extra security measure.

However, from this initial screen, it's possible to type in root as the username, and then put in root's password, and it logs you in as root.  I tried to disable this by creating an empty /etc/securetty file, but this only affected virtual consoles, (alt+cntrl+f1, etc), not the standard login screen given at startup.

I'd really rather not disable root's password, I like having that as an option, but is there another way to prevent initial login as root after startup?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "standard" login screen is shown by a display manager, usually LightDM on Ubuntu. Like /sbin/login, which handles the virtual consoles, LightDM goes through PAM for authentication & authorization, and its PAM stack can be configured through `/etc/pam.d`.

If you want `/etc/securetty` to be used, add the [pam_securetty](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man8/pam_securetty.8.html) module to to the stack.

```
auth required pam_securetty.so
```

If you want to ensure a minimum UID, use [pam_succeed_if](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man8/pam_succeed_if.8.html).

```
auth required pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  There's no pam_securetty file in my pam.d folder, but I added the line auth required pam_suceed_if.so user != root.

Comment: @anotherguy: I never said it was a file. It's a PAM module exactly like `pam_succeed_if`, and is used in the same way.